# Cumulative array aggregation in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, array

Does anybody know if it is possible perform cumulative array aggregation in Postgres? For example, to transform this:

```
create table records
(
  data text,
  path text[]
);

insert into records values
('John', '{"AAA", "BBB", "CCC"}'),
('Paul', '{"AAA", "BBB"}'),
('George', '{"AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"}'),
('Ringo', '{"EEE"}');
```

into this:

```
John    {AAA}
John    {AAA,BBB}
John    {AAA,BBB,CCC}
Paul    {AAA}
Paul    {AAA,BBB}
George  {AAA}
George  {AAA,BBB}
George  {AAA,BBB,CCC}
George  {AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD}
Ringo   {EEE}
Ringo   {EEE,FFF}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

```
select data, array_agg(unnest) over (partition by data order by ordinality)
 from records, unnest(path) with ordinality
```

In this case, the default "framing" does exactly what you want: from the beginning to the current row; so you don't have to include a framing clause.